# How to set different share in the same shareButton

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am stuck in my app trying to set a share button.
I have a simple textview to be shared with a few of social networks.
As i found out i cannot share just text with Facebook without using Facebook SDK.
Now i d like to know if is possibile to set a thing like. If user press whatsapp share my string if user press Facebook share the link of my app.
Below is my share button code.

```
case R.id.action_share:         
            Intent intent2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent2.setType("text/plain");
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, random + "\n"+"By Random Quotes" ); //random is the textview
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Share via"));
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to start activity with new task,like this:-

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "share discription");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"text you want to share");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"you share title"));
}
```

Comment: ok but how i tell android to start an activity instead another? As you know android.content ecc open an android pre-built menu with all of the social network installed. My problem is know how to set if press this open this activity if press that open that activity

Comment: you have to set the package name for the activity you want to share the text and yes i think that way you can't share with facebook with sharing intent you have to write a whole lot code

Comment: if you are using the android share intent it will show all the social networks with installed and when user selects one social network it shares the data with it.You do not have to do anything for it.But if you want to share data with a specific application you can set the package name of that application in your intent and the data will be shared with that application only but be carefull first check that the application is installed or not